# How to translate "Unable to stat %s\n" in German?

Tags: c, internationalization, po

I have a translation question but I am asking it here because I think it needs technical understanding.

In order to translate a program to German, I have this line in the `.po` file:

```
#, c-format
msgid "Unable to stat %s\n"
msgstr ""
```

What does this mean and how would I say it in German?

Comment: Use Google translate. This has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: @KobyDouek This is a highly technical usage, I doubt (and a quick attempt proved me right) that Google will get the context here.

Comment: stat auf %s konnte nicht ausgeführt werden

Comment: A technicalĺy savvy user will understand the english term, all others will not know what to do with the message anyway... If you want to express, that a file was not found, say "File %s not found" on -ENOENT, or "Permission denied on file %s" on -EPERM etc. pp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here `stat` is a reference to the POSIX standard call of that name, [`stat(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).

Perhaps you can take some clue from the manual page's description, the brief one is "get file status".

My German is waaaay too rusty to suggest a translation, but inserting it into the English would give "Unable to get file status (stat) %s\n" (I kept the original "stat" phrase since it's highly-detailed technical information and might be useful).

You could of course not try to work around the function name, and instead just say "The stat() function failed for %s", it's the use of the funtion name as a verb which makes it harder to translate, I think.

Comment: Statusabfrage (stat) für Datei '%s' fehlgeschlagen.